# A word to describe someone who thinks that what they are doing is just when it really isn't?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word to describe a character who truly believes that their toxic behavior is for another's betterment despite being told what they're doing is wrong and hurtful.

Example sentence: "Even after causing her good friend to cry, she refused to even consider the possibility she didn't help at all. She's such a ____ person!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following:

[arrogant](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/arrogant)

I like this word choice, especially meaning "2. Marked by or arising from a feeling or assumption of one's superiority toward others."

It conveys the sense of self-superior disregard you described for "a character who truly believes that their toxic behavior is for another's betterment despite being told what they're doing is wrong and hurtful."

"Even after causing her good friend to cry, she refused to even consider the possibility she didn't help at all. She's such an arrogant person!"

Here are a few more that come to mind:

[narcissistic](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/narcissistic)

[clueless](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/clueless)

[insensitive](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/insensitive)

Answer (score 1):

While it may not be complete, but to fill in the blank in your question *"Even after causing her good friend to cry, she refused to even consider the possibility she didn't help at all. She's such a ____ person!"* I would use **INCONSIDERATE**

Here is a link to [Thersaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/inconsiderate) which lists some options.  Notably the word **OBLIVIOUS** is not on the list, but I think it is related to your original question.